# automating windows driver builds

Tags: drivers, wdk

We have a printer driver that we need to build for all OS's from Windows XP to Windows 8, both x86 and x64 versions. I can do this manually using the WDK free build environments, but I need to automate the process - start a batch script and have all my builds ready.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: If you use VS2012, you can build from command line with `MSBuild.exe` now - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554644(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I'm using VS2012 for the Win8 drivers because I have to, but I prefer not to use it for everything if possible.

Comment: Ok, but if you *do* use it, you can easily write a batch script to do all your builds. I don't know of a way to do this with the WDK build tools though, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Command-line windows for x86/x64 Debug/Release  and various OS platforms differ only in enviroment variables. The scripts setting the environment variables are already available in DDK or Visual Studio. (To find out script names check properties of corrseponding command window shortcuts.) So the problem comes down to writing a Windows batch file setting environment variables and invoking build commands one by one. Most likely environment variables for each next platform overwrite ones from previous platform, but to be safe you can start each build in a separate clean cmd.exe process. Here is the main script:

```
start /W "cmd /C build_winxp_x86_debug.cmd"
start /W "cmd /C build_winxp_x64_debug.cmd"
...
start /W "cmd /C build_win8_x86.cmd"
start /W "cmd /C build_win8_x64.cmd"
```

Start /w waits for spawned cmd.exe process termination before executing the next line. Cmd /c terminates when corresponding build script completes. 
Example of build script:

```
@rem Script setting environment variables from DDK
ddkpath\setenv.bat XP x86 dbg
@rem your build commands
cd your_driver_dir
build -cz
```

Comment: after call setenv.bat ,the cmd does not eval the next code but just jump to ddk path. i am confust now.why?